# I dont understand this statement: Prove that continuity in $x$ of the Gateaux derivative implies Frechet differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization, gateaux-derivative

> Prove that continuity in $x$ of the Gateaux derivative implies Frechet differentiability

I don't understand this statement, since Gateaux derivative is a function $f(x;y)=a\cdot y$ for all $y$, defined in the point $x$ (not variable) and its variable is $y$, so I don't get what continuity in $x$ means.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first when it was defined, $x$ was assumed not to vary. On the other hand, I guess, it was also assumed to be *arbitrary* (in some domain).

So, $f(x;y)$ is defined in all $x$'s, thus later, we can do vary that point $x$.

Comment: but then $f(x;y)$ should be a fuction of two vector, so how do I define continuity for just one component?